# c# generics how to cast return type?

Tags: c#, generics

i have a dictionary

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string,string>{{"name","Smith"},{"age","20"}};
```

and i want to map it's values to a class

```
class Person{ 
public string Name {get;set;} 
public string Age {get;set;}
}
```

i tried to do it in this way

```
public T Map<T>(Dictionary<string, object> row) 
{
      var p= new Person();
      if (row.ContainsKey("name")) Person.Name= row["name"];
      if (row.ContainsKey("age")) Person.Age= row["age"];
      return (T) p;
}
```

and the problem is that i fail at return type, i dont know how to cast T to class Person.
any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: But WHY must you use generics? Doesn't sound like you need generics here at all.

Comment: But T is person somehow?

Comment: What was the point of making this method generic? It always returns `Person`, regardless of `T`.

Comment: How would you expect this method to behave if the call site were `Hospital hospital = Map<Hospital>(row);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:

```
public Person Map(Dictionary<string, object> row) 
{
      var p= new Person();
      if (row.ContainsKey("name")) Person.Name= row["name"];
      if (row.ContainsKey("age")) Person.Age= row["age"];
      return p;
}
```

Or:

```
public T Map<T>(Dictionary<string, object> row) 
 where T : Person
{
      var p= new Person();
      if (row.ContainsKey("name")) Person.Name= row["name"];
      if (row.ContainsKey("age")) Person.Age= row["age"];
      return (T) p;
}
```

Or:

```
public T Map<T>(Dictionary<string, object> row) 
 where T : Person, new ()
{
      var p= new T();
      if (row.ContainsKey("name")) Person.Name= row["name"];
      if (row.ContainsKey("age")) Person.Age= row["age"];
      return p;
}
```

Comment: The second won't work.  Consider a type `HappyPerson` derived from `Person`, and imagine what happens when calling `Map<HappyPerson>(row)`.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with this line:

```
var p= new Person();
```

You are trying to return a `Person` type, though `T` can be *anything*.

You need to add a [generic type constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) to the class, only allowing `T` to be a `Person` - though that wouldn't be very useful.

But in your case, generics are not even needed:

```
public Person Map(Dictionary<string, string> row) 
{
      var p= new Person();
      if (row.ContainsKey("name")) Person.Name= row["name"];
      if (row.ContainsKey("age")) Person.Age= row["age"];
      return p;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

T is just a type. You wouldn't be casting it to anything. If you had an instance of T, you would have (Person)T.

You can also do:
where T: Person assuming your question is just worded in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a dictionary of the form:

```
new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Smith", "20"},{"Paul","44"}}
```

You can do this easily with LINQ.  Something like:

```
dictionary
    .Select(k=>new Person()
        {
            Name=k.Key,
            Age=k.Value
        })
    .ToList();
```

With the dictionary you have, you'd have to do something like:

```
public Person GetPersonFromDictionary(Dictionary<string,string> dictionary)
{
    var myPerson = new Person()
    {
        Name=dictionary[name],
        Age=dictionary[age]
    }
    return myPerson;
}
```

Assuming you were guaranteed the dictionary had the values you needed.  I don't see any need to involve generics here.

Comment: This would work if the dictionary `new Dictionary<string,string>{{"Smith", "20"},{"Paul","44"}}` which is different than having {"<property name>", "<value>"} pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to populate the properties:

```
 public static T Map<T>(Dictionary<string, string> dictionary) where T : class, new()
    {
        var obj = new T();
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

        foreach (var item in dictionary)
        {
            var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(item.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(obj, item.Value, null);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

...

```
 var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "name", "Smith" }, { "age", "20" } };
 Person o = Map<Person>(dictionary);
```

Comment: Thank you @Strillo, your solution is interesting i will give it a try